# Animation on color switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm busy on a site, and it needs to be colorfull, so I got a list of colors, and I was like: "Hey! Lets switch container tops on click of certain menu items." So I decided to use the jQuery data attribute:

```
<a onclick="loadSubmenu(5)" class="item" data-color="006496"> <div class="point" id="blauw">
                <p>Leden</p>
            </div></a>
            <a onclick="loadSubmenu(4)" class="item" data-color="169600"> <div class="point" id="groen">
                <p>Game</p>
            </div></a>
            <a onclick="loadSubmenu(3)" class="item" data-color="967F00"> <div class="point" id="geel">
                <p>Radio</p>
            </div></a>
            <a onclick="loadSubmenu(2)" class="item" data-color="964B00"> <div class="point" id="oranje">
                <p>Nieuws</p>
            </div></a>
            <a onclick="loadSubmenu(1)" class="item" data-color="960000"> <div class="point" id="currentrood">
                <p>Home</p>
            </div></a>
```

So I defined the `data-color` at every item, lets get onto the actual jQuery code:

```
 $(".item").click(function(){
        backgroundKleur = '#' + $(this).data('color');

        changeColors(backgroundKleur);

        $(".item").removeClass('bold-font');
        $(this).addClass('bold-font');

    });
function changeColors(backgroundKleur){
    $("#submenu-container").css('background-color', backgroundKleur);
    $(".content_small_top").css('background-color', backgroundKleur));
}
```

But now, when the color switches I want to fade out the old color and fade in the new one. I tried various options like `fadeToggle` or using `slideUp` and `slideDown` at once, but non of it worked like I wanted it. Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Thanks

Comment: did you try animate? I think this is the answer. Or you can use this addon: http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Comment: @David Is it possible to do this from my current JS file?

Comment: Is this kind of what you're after? (hover the red square) http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/4fk59015/1/ -- Seems to me that you could just fade out by changing opacity to 0, then after that's complete, change the background color and fade back in.

Comment: @brbcoding Exactly! Thanks! If you put it into an answer I'll accept and upvote it for you ;D

Comment: Cool, I added the runnable snippet below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just fade out the current element (by animating the opacity to 0), update the background color, and then fade it back in after that animation completes (jquery's animate takes a callback for when the original animation is completed). I've put together a fairly generic example to illustrate this below.

```js
$('.fader').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 1000, function() {
    $this.css('background', 'blue');
    $this.animate({
      opacity: 1
    });
  });
})
```

```css
.fader {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fader"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define an empty `@keyframes` and use JavaScript to create keyframe rules on a click event this way.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o3eqbx98/) | [Check the Edit for `-webkit-` support]

#### HTML:

```
<div class="item" data-color="red">Red</div>
<br />
<div class="item" data-color="green">Green</div>
<br />
<div class="item" data-color="blue">Blue</div>
<br />
<div class="item" data-color="sienna">Sienna</div>
<br />
<div class="item" data-color="chocolate">Chocolate</div>
<br />
<div class="item" data-color="Maroon">Maroon</div>
<br />
```

#### JavaScript/jQuery:

```
function findRule() {
    var rule;
    var ss = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < ss[i].cssRules.length; ++j) {
            rule = ss[i].cssRules[j];
            if (rule.name == "changeColor" && rule.type == window.CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE) {
                return rule;
            }
        }
    }
}
var cssRule = findRule();
$('.item').click(function () {
    var color = $(this).attr('data-color');
    cssRule.appendRule("0% {color: " + $(this).css('color') + "; }");
    cssRule.appendRule("50% {color: white;}");
    cssRule.appendRule("100% { color:  " + color + "; }");
    $('.item').removeClass('animate');
    $(this).addClass('animate');
    $('.animate').css({
        'color': color
    });
});
```

#### CSS:

```
@-moz-keyframes changeColor {
}
.animate {
    animation: changeColor 2s 1;
}
div {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

### <----------------------------- [EDIT - Added support for `-webit-` browsers] -------------------------------->

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0f5Ljm28/)

#### JavaScript/jQuery:

```
function findRule() {
    var rule;
    var ss = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < ss[i].cssRules.length; ++j) {
            rule = ss[i].cssRules[j];
            if (rule.name == "changeColor" && rule.type == window.CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE) {
                return {
                    r: rule,
                    type: 'webkit'
                };
            }
            if (rule.name == "changeColor" && rule.type == window.CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE) {
                return {
                    r: rule,
                    type: ''
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
var cssRule = findRule();
$('.item').click(function () {
    var color = $(this).attr('data-color');
    if (cssRule.type == 'webkit') {
        cssRule.r.insertRule("0% {color: " + $(this).css('color') + "; }");
        cssRule.r.insertRule("50% {color: white;}");
        cssRule.r.insertRule("100% { color:  " + color + "; }");
    } else {
        cssRule.r.appendRule("0% {color: " + $(this).css('color') + "; }");
        cssRule.r.appendRule("50% {color: white;}");
        cssRule.r.appendRule("100% { color:  " + color + "; }");
    }
    $('.item').removeClass('animate');
    $(this).addClass('animate');
    $('.animate').css({
        'color': color
    });
});
```