# changing a value in css using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

```
@-webkit-keyframes swag{

   0% {-webkit-transform:translateY(0px);}      

  50% {-webkit-transform:translateY(-400px);}

 100% {-webkit-transform:translateY(0px);}

  }
```

I want to change the "-400 px" in the 50% key-frame dynamically according to the height of an another div.So can we use javascript to achieve this here ? If so,how ?

Comment: You will have to loop through the stylesheet rules and change the keyframe rules.

Comment: how can i change the key-frame rule ? should i use .css(); and write the entire animation on it ?? @ chipChocolate.py

Comment: Well, its lot more than `.css()`, I'll write an answer.

Comment: Can post value of "height of an another div" ?

Comment: It's no big deal,the value of the div changes dynamically.That's why i wanted the keyframe value to get changed aswell.@ guest271314

Comment: I found my old answer that creates new `@keyframes` dynamically using JavaScript. Hope it helps. Here it is ----> http://stackoverflow.com/a/26893071/3905567

Comment: It is helpful,thanks @ chipChocolate.py

Answer (score 1):

Better use Less (http://lesscss.org/) or Sass (http://sass-lang.com/),which are CSS dynamic languages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SASS will solve the issue you're having.. (but it's still incredibly handy to use)

Could you explain what you're trying to achieve a little more? (eg positioning, what variables on sizing etc)

Comment: This is not an "answer".